# What exactly are those data types int 16, int 32 and int 64 on the iPhone, in Core Data?

Tags: iphone, core-data

The Xcode data modeler shows me those three different int data types. When I would write code, which data types do these really correspond to on the iPhone? Are they all simply NSInteger, wrapped in an NSNumber?

As far as I see it, NSNumber only differentiates between int an NSInteger... so I guess those three end up beeing pretty much the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those values correspond to the `NSAttributeType` of `NSAttributeDescription`. These are analogous to the strings returned by `NSValue`'s `objCType` method inherited by `NSNumber`. The core data framework needs to know how to encode/decode the value in the persistent store and also which `init` method to call when creating the `NSNumber` object. The types in `NSEntityDescription` provide the ability to dynamically create the correct object from storage and save them again. Generally, you don't need to be concerned with the storage details of the `NSValue` classes and subclasses. These details are hidden on purpose. If you were implementing your own custom NSAtomicStore then you will need to know. Consult the [Atomic Store Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AtomicStore_Concepts/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004521) for further details.

Comment: So if I shouldn't care about the details, why must I choose between one of three int types? ;) Couldn't they just provide one "int" option? Or, lets say, if I choose int64...is that something like long long?

Comment: When dealing with the NSNumber object, you don't need to know, however if you are pulling values from remote data sources to create new ManagedObjects, you will have to match the storage type with the remote type to avoid overflow conditions or loss of precision.